# Are Korean dramas on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I know what is anime and manga, but could I ask about Korean dramas here? Or maybe should I ask this topic on [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome :)

Questions regarding Korean dramas would not be on topic here. You can read more about [what is on topic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our help center.

However you can take a look over at [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) Judging by their [what is on topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) list, I would assume that questions about Korean dramas are on topic. As long as the question suffices to their standards.

Comment: oh thank yoooou